# How to control a Sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to test a sequence in a table and have to delete the wrong records. Example:

```
 DATE                DriverId CodeId
 2014/03/01 14:00:00, 7168,     22     -- GO
 2014/03/01 14:30:00, 7168,     23     -- STOP
 2014/03/01 14:40:00, 7168,     22     -- GO
 2014/03/01 15:10:00, 7168,     22     -- GO     <--- delete this record
 2014/03/01 16:00:00, 7168,     23     -- STOP
```

When I deleted the worng record, I have to calculate the time between GO & Stop

Im using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Because I have to calculate time elapsed from 22 to 23, If I lost a record 23 (like the example) I have to take the next one and include this time. This is because Im receiving records by GPRS and can loose records like in the example.

Comment: Why was this question upvoted?

Comment: Could your question be rephrased delete the last one? If so what makes it the last one? Or is it arbitrary?

Comment: What is the sequence ordered by? Can you show us a example using real values instead of the placeholders `datetime var` and `int var`? Also what version of SQL Server are you using, there are features in newer versions than can help in situations like this that are not available in older versions.

Comment: ORDER By datetime - the sequence is stop and go events of a vehicle. GO = 22 STOP = 23 - Please, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dates have the sequence order, it seems that you want to delete the one where the value is the same as the previous value:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, lag(codeid) over (order by "date") as prev_codeid
      from table t
)
delete from todelete
    where prev_codeid = codeid;
```

That is SQL Server 2012 syntax.  You can do this in earlier versions with a correlated subquery:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             (select top 1 codeid
              from table t2
              where t2."date" < t."date"
              order by t2.date desc
             ) as prev_codeid
      from table t
)
delete from todelete
    where prev_codeid = codeid;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, Gordon, I will try your solution. I will comment later.